# Running code between certain times

Tags: php, datetime-format

I have php code that is suppose to run between 04:00am and 05:00am but it does not run, i cant see the problem with this?

```
  $begin = new DateTime('04:30');
    $end = new DateTime('05:00');

    while (!connection_aborted() || PHP_SAPI == "cli") {
        $now = new DateTime();

    if(date("Hi") <= $begin && date("Hi") >= $end){
    //run code
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you trying to manually run this file at that time? Are you sure your server is in the same time zone as you are? Or do you want this to automatically run at that time? If so you can just skip the times in this and set up CRON to run this script at the spesific time.

Comment: I have checked the server is in the same time zone, I wanted to use a cron job but since i need it to run every 10 second a cron job is out since a cron can only start every min. I have this running as Systemd Services.

Comment: sorry bettwen 4am and 5am, have make an edit.

Comment: @Joe Does the answer work?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies here:

```
if(date("Hi") <= $begin && date("Hi") >= $end){
```

You are trying to do "greater than" and "less than" comparisons on strings. You should use the integer values (epoch time) then you can do this.

```
if(time() >= strtotime('14:00') && time() <= strtotime('15:00')) {
    echo 'In Range2';   
} else {
    echo 'out of range2';
}
```

Note: This is for between 2:00pm and 3:00pm just to show it works (it currently is 2:00pm where I am located).

Demo: https://3v4l.org/NhnfM